# Multipart POST on AppEngine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

simple problem (am confused I could not find an answer here):

I want to do a Multipart encoded HTTP POST from my AppEngine Java servlet (outbound). AppEngine does not seem to support the Apache HTTP lib and does not offer an API themselves (only  `setPayload(byte[])`), but I would like to avoid implementing a Multipart encoding myself. So:

1. Is there a way to send Multipart HTTP bodies from AppEngine Java?
2. Is there a library that encodes such a body into a `byte[]` array? (Note that `MultiPartEntity.getContent()` is not implemented.) Then I could use the AppEngine internal URLFetch API (which I would prefer because of the async calling capabilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a little helper method that adds Multipart POST support to AppEngine (using the Apache HTTP client lib).

```
public static void addMultipartBodyToRequest(MultipartEntity entity, HTTPRequest req) throws IOException{

    /*
     * turn Entity to byte[] using ByteArrayOutputStream
     */
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    entity.writeTo(bos);
    byte[] body = bos.toByteArray();

    /*
     * extract multipart boundary (body starts with --boundary\r\n)
     */
    String boundary = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(new String(body))).readLine();
    boundary = boundary.substring(2, boundary.length());

    /*
     * add multipart header and body
     */
    req.addHeader(new HTTPHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary));
    req.setPayload(body);
}
```

The calling code then looks like this:

```
            MultipartEntity e = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            e.addPart("part1", new StringBody("value1"));
            e.addPart("part2", new StringBody("value2"));

            HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest(new URL(myUrl), HTTPMethod.POST);
            ServletHelper.addMultipartBodyToRequest(e, req);

            URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetchAsync(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MultipartEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) from [`httpmime`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/).

Hers is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025689/gae-j-how-do-i-post-a-multipart-mime-message-from-appengine-to-facebook).

Comment: thanks. I ended up writing it myself (see above, comparable solution to your link, but using the low-level URLFetch Service instead).